# Problemas al ejecutar dos operaciones seguidas en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de aplicar esta sentencia en un PHP de una página web que tengo y me tira error si trato de hacerlo de esta manera:

```
$sql = "DROP TABLE T$h ; DELETE FROM tics WHERE id_t = $h"
```

Donde `$h` es una variable que no tiene ningún problema, solo aclaro este punto. Ahora bien, si lo realizo de esta manera sí funciona:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tics WHERE id_t = $h; DROP TABLE T$h "
```

Sé que tal vez no encuentra esa tabla y pues no la borra pero pues la variable sí la imprime y solo me realiza si es como el segundo ejemplo que puse.

Todo esto está aplicado a un PHP que, claro está, incluye su conexión y todo normal solo esa sentencia me falla, o bien no sabría como realizarla de una manera bien y que pueda combinar ambas sentencias.

Comment: para poder ayudarte mejor sería bueno que pongas cuál es el error que te sale

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: probaste el cambiar las comillas? donde comillas dobles pones simples y donde simples pones dobles..... lo que no veo es la concatenacion, la variable $sql es un string, si queres meter variables dentro la mejor manera es concatenarlas. "DROP TABLE T". $h ." ; DELETE FROM tics WHERE id_t =". $h

Comment: @Sebastian en PHP, cuando se usan comillas dobles, las variables se expanden y se cambian por su valor. Por lo que hacer `"DROP TABLE $h"` es similar a hacer `"DROP TABLE ".$h`.

Comment: @User56 debes compartir el error que te da. Es esencial que añadas más detalles para llegar a la raíz del problema porque esto puede ocurrir por múltiples razones (aunque me imagino que lo más seguro es que tengas algún tipo de clave secundaria que está pidiendo que borres la tabla antes de borrar el contenido enlazado de la otra tabla). Añade código para ver los errores y compártelo, además sería bueno ver la estructura y relación entre ambas tablas. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: A simple vista diría que existe una restricción de clave foránea que impide que puedas borrar la tabla, esto es normal si no existe una cascada para delete. Esta respuesta quizás te pueda ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/281816/update-de-una-tabla-con-llaves-compuestas-en-mysql/281933#281933